# UILabel in UITableViewCell doesn't autoresize IOS 8. (autolayout)

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, sizetofit

I have a table view with a basic autolayout for cells.My issue is that cell is autoresizing based on subviews, but it doesn't autoresize based on UILabel text, cell just stays at minimum height regardless of label text.I am really desperate as I have tried EVERY approach i could find on stack overflow and was struggling with this for 3 days.

```
//!--------Set youTableView------------------------//
youTableView.delegate = self
youTableView.dataSource = self
youTableView.allowsSelection = false
youTableView.bounces = true
youTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
youTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
youTableView.registerClass(CommentNFTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Comment Cell")
youTableView.registerClass(LikeNFTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Like Cell")
youTableView.registerClass(ResponseNFTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Response Cell")
youTableView.registerClass(FollowNFTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Follow Cell")
youTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 5) // move separator line
youTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
self.youTableView.addSubview(youRefreshControl)
youRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "Get_You_Data", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

CommentNFTableViewCell.swift

```
class CommentNFTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,TTTAttributedLabelDelegate {
    var ScreenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    var didSetupConstraints = false

    var row:Int = Int()

    var profilePicture:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var commentLabel:TTTAttributedLabel = TTTAttributedLabel()

    var eventPicture:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var dateLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    var username:NSString!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(profilePicture)
        self.contentView.addSubview(commentLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(dateLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(eventPicture)

        profilePicture.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        commentLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        dateLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        eventPicture.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        commentLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
        commentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping


        dateLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        dateLabel.backgroundColor = ColorFromCode.standardBlueColor()
        dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        dateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
        dateLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        dateLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        dateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        eventPicture.layer.masksToBounds = true //without it its not gonna work
        eventPicture.layer.cornerRadius = 3

        profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true //without it its not gonna work
        profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = 20


        var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
        self.commentLabel.activeLinkAttributes = attrs
        make_Layout()

    }

    func make_Layout(){
        var views = [
            "profilePicture": profilePicture,
            "commentLabel": commentLabel,
            "dateLabel": dateLabel,
            "eventPicture": eventPicture
        ]
        var metrics = [
        ]
        var H_Constraint0 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[profilePicture(40)]-10-[commentLabel]-10-[eventPicture(40)]-10-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        var H_Constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[profilePicture(40)]-10-[commentLabel]-10-[dateLabel(40)]-10-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)

        var V_Constraint0 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[profilePicture(40)]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        var V_Constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[commentLabel(>=10)]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        var V_Constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[dateLabel(40)]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        var V_Constraint3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[eventPicture(40)]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)




        // height == width for picture


        self.contentView.addConstraints(H_Constraint0)
        self.contentView.addConstraints(H_Constraint1)
        self.contentView.addConstraints(V_Constraint0)
        self.contentView.addConstraints(V_Constraint1)
        self.contentView.addConstraints(V_Constraint2)
        self.contentView.addConstraints(V_Constraint3)
        self.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.commentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.commentLabel.frame.size.width;
    }
}
```

in tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath (its basically filling in the content, I dont think problem is here ,but just in case)

```
                let Cell:CommentNFTableViewCell = self.youTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Comment Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentNFTableViewCell

                Cell.row = indexPath.row
                // Labels

                var attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

                var fromUserString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: ColorFromCode.standardBlueColor()]
                fromUserString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: youData[indexPath.row].fromUser!.username!, attributes:attrs)
                attributedString.appendAttributedString(fromUserString)

                var url:NSURL = NSURL(scheme: "pushuser", host: fromUserString.string, path: "/")!
                Cell.commentLabel.addLinkToURL(url, withRange: NSRange(location: 0,length: fromUserString.length))
                Cell.commentLabel.delegate = self
                Cell.commentLabel.tag = indexPath.row

                var content:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
                content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " has commented on your event: " + (youData[indexPath.row].content as String), attributes:attrs)
                attributedString.appendAttributedString(content)

                // Set Event Picture
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    () -> Void in
                    Cell.DownloadEventPicture(&self.youData[indexPath.row].event!, row: indexPath.row)
                })
                Cell.UpdateEventPicture(self.youData[indexPath.row].event!, row: indexPath.row)
                Cell.UpdateProfilePicture(self.youData[indexPath.row])

                // Event Date

                let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
                dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
                dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
                Cell.dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.youData[indexPath.row].event!.date)
                let date:NSDate = self.youData[indexPath.row].metadata!.creationTime()

                var dateString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor()]
                dateString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: DateToStringConverter.getRelativeDateString(date), attributes:attrs)
                attributedString.appendAttributedString(dateString)



                Cell.highlightMentionsInString(attributedString, withColor: ColorFromCode.standardBlueColor())
                Cell.highlightHashtagsInString(attributedString, withColor: ColorFromCode.standardBlueColor())

return Cell
```

Comment: use form nib or story boards to set that

Comment: thanks for suggestion but I want purely programmatic approach